# Displaying JSON results correctly in Morris Chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Am using the following code to display MySQL data in a Morris Chart.  All works good EXCEPT if I have TWO or more records on the same day, only shows as ONE in the Morris Chart.

PHP File

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostname_membership, $username_membership, $password_membership, $database_membership);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$query = "SELECT id FROM details WHERE MemberStatus = 'Active' AND PaymentStatus NOT REGEXP 'Not'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$total_rows =  $result->num_rows;

$array = array();

foreach($mysqli->query('SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(*) FROM details GROUP BY DateAdded') as $row) {  
    $year = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['DateAdded']));
    array_push($array,array('Year'=>$year, 'Numb'=>$row['COUNT(*)'],'Total'=>$total_rows));
} 

echo json_encode($array);

$mysqli->close();
```

Morris JS

```
$.getJSON("js/morris.php", function (json) { 
    Morris.Area({
    element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: json,
    xkey: 'Year',
     xLabelFormat: function (x) {
              var IndexToMonth = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
              var month = IndexToMonth[ x.getMonth() ];
              var year = x.getFullYear();
              return month + ' ' + year;
          },
    xLabels: 'month',     
    ykeys: ['Numb','Total'],
    labels: ['Signups / Renewals','Total Active Members'],
    pointSize: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true,
dateFormat: function (x) { 
        var d = new Date(x);
        var MyDateString;
        d.setDate(d.getDate());         
        var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
        return ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) +' '+monthNames[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getFullYear();
        }
});
return false;
});
```

And my JSON Output is

```
[{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-10-28","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"1","Total":11}]
```

As you can see from above, the JSON output has two identical records

```
{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"1","Total":11},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"1","Total":11}
```

This is what shows as only ONE record on the Morris Chart.  In this case, it's only one person signed up on the 10th Nov 16, when in fact it was TWO...

FYI ONLY - TOTAL is just that - TOTAL number of Signups. Whilst I like to have this as a running total, I can't work that out either. So am not to worried about it, not unless there  is a simple solution.

What am I missing?

Comment: I reckon it has something to do with `SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(*) FROM details GROUP BY DateAdded` and/or `array('Year'=>$year, 'Numb'=>$row['COUNT(*)'],'Total'=>$total_rows)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have come up with a solution - seems to work - so far....

Replaced

```
SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(*) FROM details GROUP BY DateAdded
```

with

```
SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(*) FROM details GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded,"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Now just working on a running total...